# OpenMP parallel "for" with "static" schedule

Tags: parallel-processing, static, openmp, scheduling, parallel.for

I've a confusion or maybe a misunderstanding of the  `parallel for` behavior with a `static` schedule and default chunk size.

For example the below picture  What I excepted to have is yes the
   master thread will take an extra iteration but I excepted it would be
   at index 8 not 2!

The static schedule algorithm with default chunk size applies the
   round robin on the (#iterations / #threads) with 2 cases

1. If the #iterations is divisible by #threads like N=8 and #threads = 4. each thread will take an equal amount of iterations in round-robin fashion (straight forward case)
2. If the #iterations is not divisible by #threads. It will calculate the nearest integer of iterations divided by #threads and do the same as above

> case of N=9 --> 8 it will divide 2 2 2 2 and 1
>
> case of N=11 --> 12 it will be divided 3 3 3 and 2

threads are 0 1 2 3

[image]

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and the output you receive as **text inside your question**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use static scheduling, the OpenMP implementation will have to ensure that all iterations are computed by some thread if the number of threads does not evenly divide the number iterations.

From a load balancing perspective the compiler will try to allocate roughly the same number of iterations to each thread and to avoid that one thread receives all remaining iterations that are in excess of the division. So, in your example with N=11 and four threads, the remainder will be 3 and the first three threads 0..2 will get one extra iteration instead of assign 3 extra iterations to the last thread.

Comment: aha!, so N --> 9 and 4 threads we have reminder 1 it will be 3 2 2 2
N --> 11 and 4 threads we have 3 reminder then it will be 3 3 3 2 

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation on iterations distribution for no-chunk static schedule is wrong. Round robin distribution only specified for schedule(static,chunk), not for schedule(static) when "at most one chunk is distributed to each thread".

Iterations 0, 1 and 8 form two chunks because they are not consecutive, thus cannot be assigned to the same thread. Valid distributions of 9 iterations to 4 threads would be 3-2-2-2, 2-3-2-2, 2-2-3-2, 2-2-2-3, 3-3-2-1, etc, even 3-3-3-0 would be valid.  All the OpenMP specification says is that chunks should be approximately equal in size, without specifying exact distribution algorithm.